# What is needed to make a busybox init boot to a shell on an arm device/phone?

Tags: boot, android, busybox-init

I compiled busybox with `arm-linux-gnueabihf` for and Cortex-A/armv7-a arm device/phone. When I run the binary on android it works well. I decided to modify the android boot image. In the boot image ramdisk I have

> bin/busybox
>   init which is a link to busybox

I tried to boot with `linuxrc` in the root of the ramdisk but the phone/device reboots on boot. After I used `init` it boots and just hangs on the logo. My assumption is that it is actually doing something and just hangs when its finished. Is it because I need to have populated stuff in the `/dev` and `/proc`?

What would I need to make it show me the black screen for login?
Is it because init hasn't connected to the output monitor which is the phones lcd?
Do I have to call `busybox login` or `busybox something` in my `/etc/init.d/rcS`